# Fetch random color from api in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, get, fetch-api

How can I fetch random color from this API link http://www.colr.org/json/color/random and with that fetched color how do I change each element in the list separately, like add each color for one line of list in react.js?

```
class FetchRandomColor extends React.Component {
    state = {
        loading: true,
        color: null,
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        const url = "http://www.colr.org/json/color/random";
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({color: data.colors[0]})
    }


    render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.loading || !this.state.color ? (
            <div>loading...</div> 
            ) : (
            <div>
               div>{this.state.color}</div>
            </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<FetchRandomColor />, 
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

I tried this so far I can't find a way to take the color from the API and after that I need to implement that color to each line of the list.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you want to do? Post some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You can use Math.random() and RGBa, here is an example https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/react-random-color-change/227595